# Root SSH login works, but su/sudo to root does not work

Tags: linux, ssh, oracle, root, su

Im recently working on a clients box, and SSH into the box with root credentials work but when i try to su or sudo to root user it states incorrect password. I tried changed the root password and know im typing it correctly.

Thanks for help

Comment: I had to change settings that was added to /etc/pam.d/su by another administrator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sudo and su have different configuration files.

For sudo to work properly, the non-root user you are logging in should be either explicitly (I mean by user name) or implicitly (either in a UNIX group or in a defined set of users) permitted to run `sudo su -` If you don't know how this is configured, just follow the examples in the /etc/sudoers file

For su, check the  /etc/pam.d/su file to see if it is configured to prevent from being run.

And neither of these prevent you from logging directly into troot account from ssh, provided sshd_config file is permitting this login, which in your case, is true.

Comment: Thank you that worked great to fix the sudo problem and i figuired out the su problem!